# Batch file - how to find first folder after root?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, path

I'm completely confused with the paths.
I've variable with root folder

```
set root=D:\Data\Finished
```

I call batch file with 1 argument that contains path to file

```
c:\test\1.bat D:\Data\Finished\folder1\1.txt
c:\test\1.bat D:\Data\Finished\folder2\folder3\1.txt
c:\test\1.bat D:\Data\Finished\1.txt
```

How can i get first folder in path after root? And if there is no folder - return root? i.e:

```
D:\Data\Finished\folder1
D:\Data\Finished\folder2
D:\Data\Finished\
```

My code

```
call :setfile %FILENAME%
call :parentfolder %file_path:~0,-1%

if "%file_parent%"=="D:\Data\" (
  set ut_dir=%file_path%
) else (
  if "%file_parent%"=="D:\Data\Finished\" (
    set ut_dir=%file_path%
  ) else (
    set ut_dir=%file_parent%
  )
)

:setfile
set file=%~f1
set file_path=%~dp1
set file_name=%~nx1
goto :eof

:parentfolder
set file_parent=%~dp1
goto :eof
```

Comment: Have you written any code for this in your .bat file?

Comment: all I came up with is to use if else to compare string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set root=D:\Data\Finished

set "thePath=%~DP1"
set "result=%root%\"
for /F "delims=\" %%a in ("!thePath:%root%\=!") do set "result=%root%\%%a"

echo %result%
```

Output example:

```
C:\> test.bat D:\Data\Finished\folder1\1.txt
D:\Data\Finished\folder1

C:\> test.bat D:\Data\Finished\folder2\folder3\1.txt
D:\Data\Finished\folder2

C:\> test.bat D:\Data\Finished\1.txt
D:\Data\Finished\
```